# Xcode 4.6.3 Bug - .m file won't open or has issues in opening

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.6.3

I have a weird problem. I have Xcode 5.0, but I'm still using Xcode 4.6.3 because I want my apps to retain the iOS6 look.

The problem I have is, when I click some .m files, the file loads, then the scroll disappears (so I can't scroll down at all), and sometimes the file shows empty (but actually, the file isn't empty).

It works fine on Xcode 5, but not on the old version.

Edit : See the image below (and notice the curly brace in the bottom)

[image: xcode 4.6.3 bug]

[image: other issue]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks guys!

Comment: would love to see an answer for this, I need to use the old version for one app and have seen this a few times. Quit and restart is the only "fix" i've found

Comment: Its nothing try to expand your XCode window for the code area it should appear.

Comment: @wattson12 - I did that several times including deleting the derived data folder but in vain. I'm really frustrated with it :(

Comment: @iphonic - Noo! I've been doing development since 2+ years, and understand xcode etc. Its definitely not about code folding, etc. Its a bug.

Comment: @nithinreddy Nothing to do with your dev exp, yes its a xcode bug, and this is how I solve. Me too never experienced that before.

Comment: @iphonic Thanks for your suggestion. I tried doing that and it changed to this way :( http://i.stack.imgur.com/cIGrj.png Don't understand what the solution for this is

Comment: There used to be some problem if you open your project in higher versions of xcode, and then you try to open in lower versions, they create problems, so you should continue using the higher versions, in case you need some compatibility may be you need lower ios to support you can just simply copy the ios sdk from old xcode and use in new one..

Answer (score 1):

This sometimes works:

1. Open the file in another text editor. Textmate works for me.
2. Do a minor edit. For example: add a blank line.
3. Save the file using that text editor.

When you switch back to Xcode, the file should be restored and usable.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. Can't load one of the files on Xcode 4.6.3. It works on Xcode 5. Problem is that my app doesn't looks like it was on other version. I changed storyboard to looks like iOS6 and earlier but still all my views went up a little bit, even tables are partly hidden by navigation bar.

Also when I try to open that file whole Xcode 4.6.3 crash

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem happening here. In this case, inside the class was the following autogenerated code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
    <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
    // ...
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
[detailViewController release];
    */
}
```

Not sure why, but the culprit seemed to be the hash symbols on the first line inside the block comment. Removing those and saving from a different editor resulted in the file loading correctly in Xcode.